# How to make my if statements run again as if-else statement runs?

Tags: java, if-statement

Currently if someone inputs a date that is out of bounds it will result in the `else` statement running which is all fine and dandy, but I would like it so `if-else` statement were to run, it would rerun the `if` statements. I don't really have a solid idea on what I should do so any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Horoscope {
    public Horoscope() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String output = "Please enter a valid date";
        int month;
        int day;

        System.out.println("What is your month of birth?");
        month = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is your day of birth?");
        day = sc.nextInt();

        if((month == 3 && day >= 20 && day <= 31) || (month == 4 && day >= 1 && day <= 19)) {
            System.out.println("You are an Aries");
        }
        else if((month == 4 && day >= 20 && day <= 30) || (month == 5 && day >= 1 && day <= 20)) {
            System.out.println("You are a Taurus");
        }
        else if((month == 5 && day >= 21 && day <= 31) || (month == 6 && day >= 1 && day <= 20)) {
            System.out.println("You are a Gemini");
        }
        else if((month == 6 && day >= 21 && day <= 30) || (month == 7 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
            System.out.println("You are a Cancer");
        }
        else if((month == 7 && day >= 23 && day <= 31) || (month == 8 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
            System.out.println("You are a Leo");
        }
        else if((month == 8 && day >= 23 && day <= 31) || (month == 9 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
            System.out.println("You are a Virgo");
        }
        else if((month == 9 && day >= 23 && day <= 30) || (month == 10 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
            System.out.println("You are a Libra");
        }
        else if((month == 10 && day >= 23 && day <= 30) || (month == 11 && day >= 1 && day <= 21)) {
            System.out.println("You are a Scorpio");
        }
        else if((month == 11 && day >= 22 && day <= 31) || (month == 12 && day >= 1 && day <= 21)) {
            System.out.println("You are a Sagittarius");
        }
        else if((month == 12 && day >= 22 && day <= 31) || (month == 1 && day >= 1 && day <= 19)) {
            System.out.println("You are a Capricorn");
        }
        else if((month == 1 && day >= 20 && day <= 31) || (month == 2 && day >= 1 && day <= 18)) {
            System.out.println("You are an Aquarius");
        }
        else if((month == 2 && day >= 19 && day <= 29) || (month == 3 && day >= 1 && day <= 20)) {
            System.out.println("You are a Pisces");
        }
        else {
        System.out.println(output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using a loop (for, while, do-while).

Comment: @Avi I tried doing this but it ended up printing out an infinite amount of, "Please enter a valid date." I think I'm not understanding it correctly.

Comment: Maybe something like: boolean valid; do{ InputType input = readInput(); valid = isInputValid(input); } while(valid); Can’t really format it properly on my phone but you should get the gist of it.

Comment: Could you give an example of what exactly you are trying to do here?

Comment: I am not clear what you want when you say "rerun the if statements.

Comment: @ankitjain I'm trying to make so if someone enters an invalid date, it runs the else statement and then runs the if statements from the start again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public test() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String output = "Please enter a valid date";
        int month;
        int day;
        int k = 0;
// you can use do while loop. write some flag logic like I created k variable and it will be checked in while block
        do {
            System.out.println("What is your month of birth?");
            month = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("What is your day of birth?");
            day = sc.nextInt();

            if ((month == 3 && day >= 20 && day <= 31) || (month == 4 && day >= 1 && day <= 19)) {
                System.out.println("You are an Aries");
            } else if ((month == 4 && day >= 20 && day <= 30) || (month == 5 && day >= 1 && day <= 20)) {
                System.out.println("You are a Taurus");
            } else if ((month == 5 && day >= 21 && day <= 31) || (month == 6 && day >= 1 && day <= 20)) {
                System.out.println("You are a Gemini");
            } else if ((month == 6 && day >= 21 && day <= 30) || (month == 7 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
                System.out.println("You are a Cancer");
            } else if ((month == 7 && day >= 23 && day <= 31) || (month == 8 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
                System.out.println("You are a Leo");
            } else if ((month == 8 && day >= 23 && day <= 31) || (month == 9 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
                System.out.println("You are a Virgo");
            } else if ((month == 9 && day >= 23 && day <= 30) || (month == 10 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
                System.out.println("You are a Libra");
            } else if ((month == 10 && day >= 23 && day <= 30) || (month == 11 && day >= 1 && day <= 21)) {
                System.out.println("You are a Scorpio");
            } else if ((month == 11 && day >= 22 && day <= 31) || (month == 12 && day >= 1 && day <= 21)) {
                System.out.println("You are a Sagittarius");
            } else if ((month == 12 && day >= 22 && day <= 31) || (month == 1 && day >= 1 && day <= 19)) {
                System.out.println("You are a Capricorn");
            } else if ((month == 1 && day >= 20 && day <= 31) || (month == 2 && day >= 1 && day <= 18)) {
                System.out.println("You are an Aquarius");
            } else if ((month == 2 && day >= 19 && day <= 29) || (month == 3 && day >= 1 && day <= 20)) {
                System.out.println("You are a Pisces");
            } else {
                System.out.println(output);
                k = 1;
            }
        } while (k == 1);

    }
}
```

Comment: If the input is true, it still runs again. I would like it so if the response the user puts is true, then it would not ask again. Sorry for asking you again, thanks whether or not you answer :)

Comment: His problem is that he sets the flag to 1 if there is an invalid input, but not to 0 if there is a valid input.

Comment: I fixed it along with the code you provided me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I made an int called k and set it to 1 and ran the do while it was equal to 1 and if it resulted in a true if statement it returned 0 and ended the code.